# Plotting the graph of $\operatorname{Re}(z)<2$

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

$$\operatorname{Re}(z)<2$$

My idea was that, in the complex plane, the graph looks like a ray starting at the origin and extending up to $2$, but not including that point. Then there would have to be a little comment or some way to indicate that this applies to every angle $\theta$ around the origin, so long as the radius, $R$, is less than $2$.

However, [Wolfram plots it like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+Re%28z%29%3C2). Which one of us is more correct? I don't understand why Wolfram plots this in the $x$-$y$ axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither is correct.

With $z = x+iy$, the inequality is just $x < 2$, representing a half-plane to the left of the  vertical line $x = 2$:

[image]

Comment: Ok so what you're saying is that the question actually reads "Graph $x<2$". That makes sense. *However*, what would it be asking me to graph if it said "Graph $|z-2i|<5$"?

Comment: That's a completely different question, but read it like "the distance between $z$ and $2i$ is less than $5$", so the inequality represents what geometric figure?

Comment: I know, but the trouble I'm primarily having is understanding what they're actually asking and in what plane I'm supposed to graph this all in. I would interpret what you've written as there being 2 points in the complex plane, $z$ and $-2i$. The modulus is the distance between them, let's call it $r$. So then I would say that $r<5$ and graph a circle in the complex plane who's radius is $5$.

Comment: Yes, you get a circle (disc to be precise) centered at $2i$ (**not** $-2i$) with radius $5$.

Comment: So the radius being $5$ is correct? I just assumed that, but I thought it wouldn't be right because then that wouldn't fulfill the whole $r<5$ part.

Comment: Yes. But you get the *open* disc, the actual circle is not included.

Comment: Ohhhhhh it all makes sense now! That's why it's a disc!! Thank you so much!!